# How can I make my knockout simple binding work?

Tags: javascript, knockout-3.0

I have a simple binding.

See below:

```
self.test = params.reservationDetail.PaymentDetail().nameOnCreditCard();
```

and HTML for that

```
<span data-bind="text: $parent.test"></span>
```

The above code works fine, but when I update the signature and try to access this `paymentDetail()` directly in HTML, it does not allow me. I am not getting any error nor output.

Here is what I am trying to do:

```
self.test = params.reservationDetail.PaymentDetail();
```

and HTML looks like this:

```
<span data-bind="text: $parent.test.nameOnCreditCard"></span>
```

I have tried `$parents[0]`, `$parents[1]`, `$root` and other options too but did not succeed.

Comment: debug the value by doing this `<span data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($parent.test.nameOnCreditCard())"></span>` or this `<span data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($parent.test)"></span>`

Comment: Any luck? If not, and you still need help, please show console.log of  `params.reservationDetail.PaymentDetail()`

Comment: @Ray I think the issue was different, i am using inheritance based approach, now there was a little glitch, so when I tried to access the `paymentDetail()`, subscribers emptying values of some property as per earlier logic, once everything work, I will post answer here. Thanks for your consideration.